# Oracle: very slow query example. How to speed it up by looking at session browser?

Tags: oracle, indexing

I'm going to detail in every aspect a query which is really slow. Can you give me some advice to understand what should I consider to speed it up?

It involves just two tables.

```
  SELECT /*+ leading(tb) */![enter image description here][1]
        DISTINCT COUNT (huB.FLH_ID_MESSAGGIO), hub.flh_STATO, TB.LOTTO
    FROM ENI_FLUSSI_HUB HUB, NETATEMP.TMP_GAB_RECOVERY_SCARTI tb
   WHERE     HUB.FLH_ID_MESSAGGIO = tb.FLH_ID_MESSAGGIO
         AND hub.FLH_TIPO_PROCESSO_COD = tb.FLH_TIPO_PROCESSO_COD
         AND TB.LOTTO IN (:"SYS_B_0", :"SYS_B_1", :"SYS_B_2", :"SYS_B_3")
         AND HUB.FLH_FLAG_ANN = :"SYS_B_4"
GROUP BY hub.flh_STATO, TB.LOTTO
ORDER BY HUB.FLH_STATO
```

[image]

The first index script:

```
CREATE INDEX NETATEMP.ENI_ETAI_IDX2 ON NETATEMP.TMP_GAB_RECOVERY_SCARTI
(LOTTO, OPERATORE)
NOLOGGING
TABLESPACE NETATEMP_IDXTI
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   2
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            NEXT             1M
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
            FLASH_CACHE      DEFAULT
            CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
           )
NOPARALLEL;
```

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What happens if you remove the `/*+ leading(tb) */` hint?

Comment: It become very very slow. With the leading hint it takes 1', without it takes 11'. But the surprising thing is that using cursor_sharing_exact hint it takes just 1 second.